# swift proxy server not running

Tags: server, proxy, openstack

We are making a private cloud using openstack manual install guide of essex version. We have reached the swift configuration part. For installing swift we need 5 components ,proxy server being the one. The configuration file for swift proxy server is as follows:

`/etc/swift/proxy-server.conf`

```
[DEFAULT]
bind_port = 8080
user = swift
swift_dir = /etc/swift

[pipeline:main]
# Order of execution of modules defined below
pipeline = catch_errors healthcheck cache authtoken keystone proxy-server

[app:proxy-server]
use = egg:swift#proxy
allow_account_management = true
account_autocreate = true
set log_name = swift-proxy
set log_facility = LOG_LOCAL0
set log_level = INFO
set access_log_name = swift-proxy
set access_log_facility = SYSLOG
set access_log_level = INFO
set log_headers = True
account_autocreate = True

[filter:healthcheck]
use = egg:swift#healthcheck

[filter:catch_errors]
use = egg:swift#catch_errors

[filter:cache]
use = egg:swift#memcache
set log_name = cache

[filter:authtoken]
paste.filter_factory = keystone.middleware.auth_token:filter_factory
auth_protocol = http
auth_host = 127.0.0.1
auth_port = 35357
auth_token = admin
service_protocol = http
service_host = 127.0.0.1
service_port = 5000
admin_token = admin
admin_tenant_name = service
admin_user = swift
admin_password = swift
delay_auth_decision = 0

[filter:keystone]
paste.filter_factory = keystone.middleware.swift_auth:filter_factory
operator_roles = admin, swiftoperator
is_admin = true
```

After creating the proxy-server configuration file,we configured account,object, container server and swift rings.then we ran the following command:

```
sudo swift-init main start
```

all the remaining 4 components were running except proxy server.It gave the following error:

```
Error:trying to load config /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf:File contains no section headers.
file: /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf , line:1
'[DEFAULT]\n'
```

Please help..!

Comment: Please post the contents of the log file of swift, it might be in `/var/log/swift`.

Comment: Thanks for your time jobin!                                At first i was unable to access my log directtory, then i changed my certificate iformation by using the command; 'openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out cert.crt -keyout cert.key'....then i was able to enter my log directory, but whtn i listed the contents of log directory no swift file or directory found. Do you still want me to post the contents of the log file?

Comment: It is difficult to know the exact issue without the logs, can you check where exactly are swift logs stored?

Comment: hey..we solved the problem...swift proxy-server is running...

Comment: hey..we solved the problem...swift proxy-server is running... but got stuck on the following command: 'swift -v -V 2.0 -A http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/ -U service :swift -K swift stat' showing error- Account HEAD failed:http://localhost:8080/v1/AUTH_keystone tenant service-id 401 unauthorised.

Comment: We ran the command                                         '$ sudo sh -c 'zcat /usr/share/doc/swift-proxy/proxy-server.conf-sample.gz > /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf'

update'                                                        And updated /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf file, at that point the proxy server was running, but when we restarted it, it gave the same error as before..so now we have two errors :(...please help!

Comment: Please write the comment you gave as an answer and mark it as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: i also dont know how to check swift logs!